# Slide toggle text content inline within a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've looked for a similar question to my issue, but it appears I'm unique.
So I have a list of divs that have a `<a>` tag within them which then toggles out an inline description which is within a hidden span tag inside the parent div.

I'm relying on the jQuery UI library to animate the sliding toggle. jQuery toggle and slideToggle by default is just not suitable for what I want - i only want to animate smoothly along x axis (width).

Here is an example of the HTML code:

```
<div class="links" id="qanzac100">
  Q ANZAC 100 <a class="first">+</a>
  <span class="hide"> brings our shared history to life and creates a renewed legacy for future generations.
  </span>
</div>
```

I've made the jQuery/JS script loop as such:

```
// jQuery toggle for other sites buttons
$(document).ready(function() { //supposed to stop FOUC
  $(".hide").hide();

  $(".first").click(function() {

    if ($(this).html() == '+') {
      $(this).html('-')

    } else if ($(this).html() == '-') {
      $(this).html('+')
    }

    $(this).next('.hide').toggle("slide", "right", 500);
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Everything works but when the slide action animates, it slides out on a new line (block) and then when animation is finished it 'flicks' back into the inline style I originally set for it.

For better illustrative purposes, here is the JS Fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/dx8fd51f/10/

I just want it to smoothly slide out and show all on the same line and if it needs to push out to the next line, it does that when it hits the max width.

Is that possible using the jQuery toggle library?

Comment: It's so fast I don't actually see any animation at all...

Comment: Ok, so just slow the animation speed down https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/dx8fd51f/15/

Comment: I tried that it didn't seem to want to update, even your new link doesn't run any slower for me. ///nvm I fixed it.

Comment: So.. what should happen to the other tags if the text is too big..? Them jump to next line..?

Comment: How strange, try this link to a demo of my GIT branch https://rawgit.com/SLQ-web/Packery-Mockup-SLQ-Homepage/Other-Sites-(Ryan)/html/whats-on-flickity.html - Yes the other elements just get pushed down to next line if text is too big

Comment: Strange glitchy animation happening on first two links (got to press on the +/- button to toggle animation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the jQuery UI library that you are using.

It actually replaces your `span` element with a `div` with a class of `ui-effects-wrapper` and of course a `div`'s standard display type is `block`.

If you look at this [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx8fd51f/27/) you can see why it does that. It's to avoid the text that is sliding in from overlapping the text that is already there.
(In that fiddle I overrode the display style of `ui-effects-wrapper`.)

There are several ways you could fix this but the easiest would be to not rely on the UI library and just use class toggles to run the animation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I really did not want to use the UI lib (mainly because its HUGE!) but the default toggle animation was making my div elements 'jumpy' when animating. That's most likely more from slideToggle function than just 'toggle. So I modified the JS call to: $(this).next('.hide').toggle("fast"); https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/dx8fd51f/28/ and it seems to work ok.